# Last used files crash on openFileChooserDialog in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk, linux-mint, mate

I work with openFileChooserDialog() in TideSDK:

```
Ti.UI.openFileChooserDialog(callbackFunc, options);
callbackFunc = function(filenames){  
    fileSelected = filenames[0];
    console.log('---');
    console.log(fileSelected);
    console.log('---');
};
var options = {  
   multiple: false,  
   title: "Select files to open...",  
   types: ['txt'],  
   typesDescription: "Documents",  
   path: Ti.Filesystem.getUserDirectory()  
};
```

Everything is ok when i Choose file on my disk, but...
I use Linux Mint 13 x64 Mate and I have "recent opened files" helper on my files dialogs. When I choose file from these fields my app on TideSDK, confirm by OK button, app crash :(
Is dependent from my System or TideSDK? Is any solution for this on Linux?

[recent files on file chooser dialog screen](http://7pl.info/hack/recent_files_file_chooser.png)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an open issue with TideSDK: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/196

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this bug in my fork and made pull request: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/pull/233